# Why do we have different set theories

Tags: set-theory

Why do we have different set theories like Zermelo Fraenkel  Set Theory , Von Neumann Bernays Godel Set Theory and Morse Kelly set theory?

Comment: Because different authors chose different solutions ("safer", "riskier") to the paradoxes of the original (naive) set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we do calculus or algebra, we are usually considering a few basic axioms as true in our "universe". These are fundamental axioms because they can't be proven. The axiom of choice is one such axiom. So when I say I am using the Zermelo-Fraenkel framework, then it means I am accepting a set of such axioms as universal law for the mathematics I am going to perform. If I say I use $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then it means I am also including the axiom of choice in addition to the $\mathsf{ZF}$ axioms. It is necessary to specify our universe sometimes: it can directly influence the theorems that we can use.